# Work out at/come out at

Tags: american-english, phrasal-verbs

Do the phrasal verbs in the title only mean "to add up"? Or can they mean "any mathematical calculation"?

Like:

> This price works out at(comes out at) $30 per week.

Or should it only be:

> The fares work out at/comes out to $500.

**Is it natural to use it for any mathematical calculation like division, multiplication or subtraction?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *come out to/at sth* describes a result after any mathematical operation.

An example of division would be

> A 10-month program costs $2000, which comes out to $50 a week.